# Karma rendering html over test results

Tags: angular, karma-jasmine

Should I exclude the material theme.scss, I get this...

[image: Should I exclude the material theme.scss, I get this...]

However, should I include the theme, I get this...
[image: However, should I include the theme, I get this...]

I've searched for about an hour and a half now, there seems to be no way around this.

I just want to test my app and use angular material at the same time... I'd settle for turning off the rendered html ?

Comment: So what is the problem? Does it fail because of that or what?

Comment: No it doesn't fail it's just rendering the html over the test results

Comment: I assume you know which component it is, try to add `afterEach()` into the test class and add a call `componentFixture.destroy()` to destroy your component after each test, and it should disappear after all tests run.

Comment: Ahh this should be the answer thank you ! Can you add as an answer so I can set it as the answer?

Answer (score 1):

I assume you know which component it is, try to add afterEach() into the test class and add a call `componentFixture.destroy()` to destroy your component after each test, and it should disappear after all tests run.